# How do I detect user's location from a webpage opened in the Android browser?

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation, gps

Visiting [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) on the Android browser (or even with an android spoofed user-agent), presents the option to **"Share Location"**. When clicked, it uses the GPS/Cell phone towers to figure out the location. I tried the *google.loader.clientLocation* but that only works using the IP address.

Is there a method to tap into the Android OS and access GPS data from a regular web application (and not an Android application) similar to the way Google does?

*[Perhaps Google uses the Google Gears app on Android to access this data.]*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying that recently and found this forum posting interesting. I did not find a real good way to do this either and it doesn't look like we can do that without writing our own app which opens a browser instance.
http://androidforums.com/support/8868-how-get-gps-coordinates-browser.html

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful and it looks like Google Gears is what helps to retrieve the location. 
Some sample code is here and I will give it a shot soon:
http://www.ajaxapp.com/2009/03/25/google-gear-geolocation-api-example-displays-your-location-on-google-map/

Answer (score 3):

This is an HTML5 API, and it'll work on Webkit-derivatives, Chrome, and Firefox 3.5 (for now).

- http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html
- http://merged.ca/iphone/html5-geolocation

Answer (score 0):

Here is also a nice example: http://klauskjeldsen.dk/w3c-geolocation-api-html5/

Comment: As of now, Google has the best resource in my opinion, it tries the W3C and if not, it tries Google Gears to get the geolocation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#DetectingUserLocation