# How can i read GPS info from a browser in tablet c#.net

Tags: c#, android, browser, gps

I have an application which is web based. When my clients access that website from their tablets, I need to record their GPS co-ordinates. Can any one please help me on figuring out how I can do that? My application is an c#.net application. I want to upload the client's location continuously to the server

Comment: How exactly is an android user going to be running your C# application?  Outside of that you won't be able to do this with only server code.

Comment: no the android user only uses the browser, he will browse aspx pages from there i need to send the co-ordinates to the server

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Geolocation browser api](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959141/how-do-i-detect-users-location-from-a-webpage-opened-in-the-android-browser) question for more information. One thing to consider is that this will whatever location the device has and may not use the gps if it isn't turned on.